# Given that $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^3-2x^2+3x+5=0$ find $(x_2-x_1)^2(x_3-x_1)^2(x_3-x_2)^2$.

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics, symmetric-polynomials, discriminant

Consider the polynomial:

$$x^3-2x^2+3x+5=0$$

where $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ are the roots of the above polynomial. Now, consider the following determinant, which is defined using the above given roots:

$$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ 
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

And what is asked of me is to find $\Delta^2$.

After a bit of manipulation I found the following:

$$\Delta = (x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)$$

Interestingly enough, this type of matrix has a special name: [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and instead of doing that bit of manipulation after which I arrived at the above expression for $\Delta$, I could've used the formula given on that wikipedia page. Anyways...

So, I have to find:

$$\Delta^2 = (x_2-x_1)^2(x_3-x_1)^2(x_3-x_2)^2$$

The problem is that I cannot find any of the roots. I used the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and found that there are no rational roots. None of the divisors of the free term, $5$, give $0$ when plugged into the polynomial. I tried all options: $\{\pm 1, \pm 5 \}$ and they all give something $\ne 0$.

So then I used the notation:

$$f(x) = x^3-2x^2+3x+5$$

found the derivative:

$$f'(x) = 3x^2-4x+3$$

and I observed that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So the function $f$ is strictly increasing, so we can have at most one solution to $f(x) = 0$. Because of what I showed above, this solution cannot be rational. So I concluded that we have **one rational root** and **two complex (and conjugate, since $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]$) roots**. But this is as far as I got. I cannot find them. And I tried finding $\Delta^2$ without finding the roots, but I couldn't solve that either.

Comment: the squared expression is called the disciminant. Worthwhile working this out carefully

Comment: tell you what: if $x_1, x_2$ are the roots of $Ax^2 + B x + C,$ use the "symmetric" polynomials $x_1 + x_2$ and $x_1 x_2$ to find this (squared) discriminant, defined as $(x_1-x_2)^2$

Comment: @WillJagy But what do I do in this case, where the degree of the polynomial is $3$ instead of $2$?

Comment: You have good answers. I had hoped to give you a related practice problem that you could already do yourself.

Comment: @user1502, Why did you delete your answer? I thought it was good (I upvoted it).

Comment: @Atticus I deleted it because it consisted of the same method that user8675309 used, but I didn't notice it (and he posted it 19 hours earlier than me). I felt like the right thing to do was to delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'easy way' to do this leans on power sums instead of elementary symmetric polynomials.  We are implicitly working in $\mathbb C$ for this problem.

For any degree $n$ monic polynomial, first encode it in an $n$ x $n$ Companion matrix $C$.

now consider the power sum for $k\in\{1,2,3,...,\}$
$s_k := \lambda_1^k + \lambda_2^k +....+ \lambda_n^k = \text{trace}\big(C^k\big)$ and
$s_0:= n$
and $\lambda_i$ are the roots to your polynomial / the eigenvalues of $C$

now consider the matrix
$M_n := \begin{bmatrix}
s_0 & s_1  & s_2 & \cdots & s_{n-1}\\ 
s_1 &  s_2&  s_3 & \cdots & s_n \\ 
s_2& s_3 & s_4 & \cdots & s_{n+1}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
s_{n-1} & s_{n} & s_{n+1}  & \cdots  & s_{2n-2}
\end{bmatrix}$
for your problem here it is just

$M_3 := \begin{bmatrix}
s_0 & s_1  & s_2\\ 
s_1 &  s_2&  s_3\\ 
s_2& s_3 & s_4 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
(note: matrix multiplication is only needed to get $s_2$.  You get $s_0$ and $s_1$ immediately.  Also $s_3$ and $s_4$ are obtainable by Cayley Hamilton.)

and
$\det\big(M_3\big) = \Delta^2 = (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)^2(\lambda_3-\lambda_2)^2$

because
$M= V^TV \longrightarrow \det\big(M\big)=\det\big(V^TV\big)=\det\big(V^T\big)\det\big(V\big)=\det\big(V\big)^2$
(note that is a transpose, *not* conjugate transpose.  This factorization turns out to be quite useful.)

where, for avoidance of doubt, $V$ is the Vandermonde matrix, shown below for the $n=3$ case
$V := \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \lambda_1  & \lambda_1^2 \\ 
1 &  \lambda_2&  \lambda_2^2\\ 
1 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_3^2 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

$\Delta$ is not symmetric, but $\Delta^2$ is, so it can be expressed in terms of $a=x_1+x_2+x_3$, $b=x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$ and $c=x_1x_2x_3$. Indeed, we have:

$$\Delta^2 = a^2 b^2 + 18 abc - 4 b^3 - 4 a^3 c - 27 c^2$$

The simplest way I know to prove this identity, is like this: let $x=x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1$ and $y=x_1x_2^2+x_2x_3^2+x_3x_1^2$. Then:

$$\Delta^2=(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy$$

It's pretty simple to notice that $x+y=ab-3c$ and for $xy$, expanding:

$$xy=c(x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3)+(x_1^3x_2^3+x_2^3x_3^3+x_3^3x_1^3)+3c^2$$

and for the sum of cubes we have the well-known factorization:

$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3 = 3c+a(a^2-3b)$$

and similarly:

$$x_1^3x_2^3+x_2^3x_3^3+x_3^3x_1^3=3c^2+b(b^2-3ca)$$

Replacing back all of this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
xy &= c[3c+a(a^2-3b)]+[3c^2+b(b^2-3ca)]+3c^2\\
&= b^3 - 6 a b c + 9 c^2 + ca^3 
\end{aligned}
$$

and thus:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta^2 &= (ab-3c)^2-4(b^3 - 6 a b c + 9 c^2 + ca^3 )\\
&= a^2b^2+18abc-4b^3-4a^3c-27c^2
\end{aligned}
$$

And we can determine $a,b,c$ from Vieta's ($a=2, b=3, c= -5$). In the end $\Delta^2=-1127$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you got the relation $\Delta ^ 2 = a^2b^2 + 18abc - 4b^3 -4a^3c - 27c^2$? I kept raising the terms to the second power and then multiplying and adding, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: @user1502, I edited to add some more detail. Let me know if there's something else that's not clear.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_1+x_2+x_3=3u$, $x_1x_2+a_1x_3+x_2x_3=3v^2$ and $x_1x_2x_3=w^3$.

Thus, $$u=\frac{2}{3},$$ $$v^2=1,$$ $$w^3=-5$$ and
$$(x_1-x_2)^2(x_1-x_3)^2(x_2-x_3)^2=$$
$$=27(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)=$$
$$=27\left(\frac{4}{3}-4+\frac{160}{27}-20-25\right)=-1127.$$

Comment: How come you are allowed to use those $3$ notations? You are treating $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ as if they are equal to each other, but they are clearly not. I have issues understanding how you came up with those $3$ notations and how come they work?

Comment: @user1502 I always work with this discriminant and I just know this expression of $u$ $v^2$ and $w^3$. I am ready to explain, how I got this result. I got it by hand 15 years ago. But now, you can check it by the WA.

Answer (score 2):

For a cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$,

the roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$ have the following properties:

$x_1+x_2+x_3=-\frac ba$

$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=\frac ca$

$x_1x_2x_3=-\frac da$

Since you have $x^3-2x^2+3x+5=0$,

$x_1+x_2+x_3=2$

$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=3$

$x_1x_2x_3=-5$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: That's the problem, I can't do the rest. I already knew what you wrote there, but I can't continue it.

Answer (score 1):

Since  $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are the roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c$, they are the  eigenvalues of  the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & -c \\
1 & 0 & -b\\
0 & 1 & -a
\end{matrix} \right)$$

Now we have
$$f(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$$
so
$$f'(x) = (x-x_2)(x-x_3) + (x-x_1)(x-x_3) + (x-x_2)(x-x_3)$$
and from this we get
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x_1) = (x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)\\
f'(x_1) = (x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)\\
f'(x_3) = (x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)
\end{eqnarray}
and so
$$\Delta = (x_1-x_2)^2(x_1-x_3)^2(x_2-x_3)^2 = - f'(x_1) f'(x_2)f'(x_3)$$

Now, $f'(x_i)$, $i=1,3$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $f'(A)$.
We conclude

$$\Delta = - \det f'(A) = - \det ( 3 A^2 + 2 a A + b I_3)= -  \left| \begin{matrix}  b & -3 c & a c \\ 2a & -2 b & a b - 3 c \\ 3 & - a& a^2 - 2 b \end{matrix} \right |$$
and so the [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Discriminant%5B%20x%5E3%20%2B%20a%20x%5E2%20%2B%20b%20x%20%2B%20c%2C%20x%5D) is
$$\Delta = - 4 a^3 c  + a^2 b^2 + 18 a b c - 4 b^3  - 27 c^2$$

Answer (score 0):

> Given $x_1,x_2,x_3$ as roots of
> \begin{align}x^3-2x^2+3x+5&=0 \tag{1}\label{1} \\ \text{and }\quad \Delta &= (x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)(x_3-x_1) \tag{2}\label{2} \end{align}
> find $\Delta^2$.

Surprisingly, the [Ravi substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/ravi-substitution)
works smoothly in this case, despite that
$x_1,x_2,x_3$ are complex numbers rather than positive reals,
as well as
the "sides" $a,b,c$, "semiperimeter" $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$,
"inradius" $r$ and "circumradius" $R$
of the corresponding "triangle"
are also most possibly complex.

So, using a substitution

\begin{align}
x_1&=\rho-a
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
x_2&=\rho-b
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
x_3&=\rho-c
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\text{and }\quad
x&=\rho-y
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

in \eqref{1}, we have a cubic equation

\begin{align}
y^3+(-3\rho+2)\,y^2+(3\rho^2-4\rho+3)\,y-\rho^3+2\rho^2-3\rho-5&=0
\tag{7}\label{7}
\end{align}

which roots are $a,b,c$.

Given that $a,b,c$ are also the roots of the cubic

\begin{align}
y^3-2\rho\,y^2+(\rho^2+r^2+4\,r\,R)\,y-4\rho\,r\,R&=0
\tag{8}\label{8}
,
\end{align}

we can trivially find that
we must have $\rho=2$, thus \eqref{7}, \eqref{8}
are simplified to
\begin{align}
y^3-4y^2+7y-11&=0
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
y^3-4y^2+(4+r^2+4rR)\,y-8\,r\,R &= 0
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{align}

and we can conclude that

\begin{align}
r\,R&=\frac{11}8
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
r^2&=-\frac52
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}

With the substitution of \eqref{5}-\eqref{7},
question becomes to find

\begin{align}
\Delta^2&=(b-a)^2(c-b)^2(a-c)^2
\tag{13}\label{13}
.
\end{align}

Using the known expression of the r.h.s of \eqref{13}
in terms of $\rho,r,R$,

\begin{align}
\Delta^2&=
4\,r^2\,(4R\,(\rho^2\,(5r+R)-r\,(4R^2+3\,(r+2R)^2))-(\rho^2+r^2)^2)
\tag{14}\label{14}
\end{align}

with $\rho=2$ we have

\begin{align}
\Delta^2&=
320\,(rR)\,r^2+64\,(rR)^2-256\,(rR)^3-48\,(r^2)^2\,(rR)-192\,r^2\,(rR)^2-64\,r^2
-32\,(r2)^2-4\,(r^2)^3
.
\tag{15}\label{15}
\end{align}

Finally, the substitution of \eqref{11}-\eqref{12} into \eqref{15}
gives the result
\begin{align}
\Delta^2&=-1127
\tag{16}\label{16}
,
\end{align}

which agrees with the other answers.

---

**Edit**

Using the same approach, the answer for a general cubic
\begin{align}
x^3+u\,x^2+v\,x+w&=0
\tag{17}\label{17}
\end{align}

can be found to be

\begin{align}
\Delta^2&=u^2 v^2+18\,u\,v\,w-4v^3-4u^3\,w-27w^2
\tag{18}\label{18}
.
\end{align}